# GraphQL Apollo: Variable was not provided error in apollo client query, although I think I set the variable

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-client

What is wrong with this basic apolloClient query?

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

export default (context, apolloClient, userId) => (
  apolloClient.query({
    query: gql`
      query RootQueryType($userId: ID!) {
        verifyUser(
          id: $userId
        ) {
          id,
          token
        }
      },
    `,
    options: {
      variables: { userId: userId }
    }
  }).then(({ data }) => {
    return { loggedInUser: data }
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
    return { loggedInUser: {} }
  })
)
```

I do get the error `Error: GraphQL error: Variable "$userId" of required type "ID!" was not provided.`. But I set the options and variables with this data.
I don't see, what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the problem in the query definition:

```js
gql `
query RootQueryType($userId: ID!) {
verifyUser(
userId: $userId // here you need the parameter to be userId
) {
    id,
    token
  }
}`
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I hardly see any difference in yours and the op

Comment: The main difference in the question and the answer is this:
Question:
verifyUser(id: $userId)
Answer:
verifyUser(userId: $userId)

This needs to be like that because in the definition of the query the userId parameter is requested. Thats what the graphQL error is trying to tell

Answer (score 0):

The first userID should be **id** instead of **userID**, it should also be defined as **id** in the Apollo server to match your query..

**Change:**

```js
options: {
  variables: { userId: userId }
}
```

**To:**

```
options: {
  variables: { id: userId }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue. Make sure your variable is

- string `"userId": "1"` not number `"userId": 1`
- without `$` sign `"userId": "1"` not `"$userId": "1"` also not `userId`

I was setting as `$userId: 1` but correct one was `"userId": "1"`